# Override class level @Path annotation on the method

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have two java files that contain endpoints that deal with file management. One is called FileResource.java and the other is DirectoryResource.java. DirectoryResource.java has only one method, which is **createDirectory**. I need to move that method over to FileResource.java and remove DirectoryResource.java completely.

The problem is that the endpoint for the createDirectory method is currently **/api/dir/create**. When I move it over to FileResource.java it won't work anymore because the class-level @Path annotation is at **"/file/"** instead of **"/dir/"**.

Here's my question: **Is it possible to override the @Path annotation on the method so that I can to maintain the endpoint /api/dir/create after moving it to the FileResource class?**

I want to make sure that those who are using the api don't have to refactor their code to point to a new endpoint.

```
//FileResource.java
...

@Path("/file/")
public class FileResource() {

  @POST
  @Path("create")
  public Response createFile(String fileContent) {
    ...
    return Response.ok().build();
  }

  ...
}


//DirectoryResource.java
...

@Path("/dir/")
public class DirectoryResource() {

  @POST
  @Path("create")
  public Response createDirectory(String path) {
    ...
    return Response.ok().build();
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: One possible workaround : move your annotation from class level to method level, if you want to keep them under the same Path. Ex: @Path("/file/create") public Response createFile(){...} , @Path("/dir/create") public Response createDir(){...} .

Comment: @Daniel You are correct. That would work and I may have to do that if I can't find another solution. I would like to avoid that solution if possible.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You cannot override paths, but there are multiple workarounds to your solution  : using regex-es on your class path, keep paths only at method level, and other workarounds I can't imagine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no 'overriding' of `@Path` annotation. They **add**.

Method annotated with `@Path("create")` in the class annotated with `@Path("dir")` will resolve to `/dir/create`.

You define the path by defining correct methods in correct channels. You move methods and delete channels only if you need to change pathes.

I see no reason you need to change the channel without changing the API, but if you still need to, you should play, for example, with `mod_rewrite` on Apache. But I'd advise against it. Just keep your channels structure clean.

Comment: This is what my research had led me to. I just wanted to double check if anyone knew something I didn't. This is a requirement for work and not something that I would necessarily try to do on a personal project. Thanks for the answer though.